# How to add multiple values to the same key in Map

Tags: java

I have tried as below :

```
for (Object[] trials: trialSpecs) {
    Object[] result= (Object[]) trials;
    multiValueMap.put((Integer) result[0], new ArrayList<Integer>());
    multiValueMap.get(result[0]).add((Integer)result[1]);
}
```

But every time the new value is replaced with the old value. I know this is because of `new ArrayList<Integer>` I used in the code.

But I am not able to replace this block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `put` a `new ArrayList()` if one is not already present:

```
for (Object[] trials: trialSpecs) { 
    Object[] result= (Object[]) trials; 
    //Check to see if the key is already in the map:
    if(!multiValueMap.containsKey((Integer) result[0]){
        multiValueMap.put((Integer) result[0], new ArrayList()); 
    }
    multiValueMap.get(result[0]).add((Integer)result[1]); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. actually i have iterate around 10k records, is this is the best way to do it? or do we have any way to just convert a list to map without iteration?

Comment: The List is returned from JPA query

Comment: This is the only way to do it.  Even if you were to somehow find a 3rd party library from somebody to accomplish the task (say, guava's multimap), this is what they would do under the hood (or at the minimum, they'd do something so similar as to make the differences meaningless).  Also, 10k records is really a small number, not even a challenge

Comment: Thanks much  StormeHawke!

Comment: @Suresh If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark to the left under the votes

Answer (score 3):

java libraries like Guava and Apache propose the Multimap that does exactly that:

With [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap):

```
Multimap<String, String> mhm = ArrayListMultimap.create();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
Collection<String> coll = mhm.get(key);
```

With [apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html):

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```